# How to configure embedded kernel to use serial line for PPP instead of TTY

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, serial-console, ppp, uart

I am about to start working on an embedded system which runs kernel v2.6.x.

It is configured to use its serial line as a TTY (accessible via e.g. minicom, stty), but I want to run IP over the serial line so that I can run multiple multiplexed sessions over the link (e.g. via UDP/TCP or SSH).

I don't have much more information about the boards yet (will post more when the documentation arrives), but assuming that the kernel provides reasonable abstraction over the hardware - what would be the process to configure it to run PPP or (C)SLIP over the serial link in place of TTY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first disable `getty` running on your serial port device `/dev/ttyS0` (or whatever it is named for your hardware) to free it (for example, by editing `/etc/inittab` and running `telinit q` - if you managed to steer away from systemd)  and then you would run `pppd(8)` on it (either manually with appropriate parameters or via additional tools like `wvdial`)

Comment: Once I have the board, I'll mark this answer as accepted if it helps.  Otherwise, I'll post more information about the environment.

Comment: The board arrived, and the kernel lacks support for PPP / SLIP, so I'm building my own kernel.  This could take a couple of days to get right (+ the bootloader), so I'm accepting your answer now.